# Get first item from multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got the following array, called `$images`:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => int 69
      'alt' => string 'alt text' (length=8)
      'title' => string 'Image TItle' (length=11)
      'caption' => string 'Image caption' (length=13)
      'description' => string 'description' (length=11)
      'mime_type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'url' => string 'http://journal.wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/url.jpg' (length=52)
      'width' => int 259
      'height' => int 194
      'sizes' => 
        array (size=9)
          'thumbnail' => string 'http://journal.wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/url-150x150.jpg' (length=60)
          'thumbnail-width' => int 150
          'thumbnail-height' => int 150
          'medium' => string 'http://journal.wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/url.jpg' (length=52)
          'medium-width' => int 259
          'medium-height' => int 194
          'large' => string 'http://journal.wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/url.jpg' (length=52)
          'large-width' => int 259
          'large-height' => int 194
```

And I need to get the attribute `'thumbnail'`. I am currently using:

```
echo $images[0][0]['thumbnail'];
```

Which receives nothing. What is the correct way to always get the first `thumbnail`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with:

```
echo $images[0]['sizes']['thumbnail'];
```

Comment: '0' is not always first index.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the first element of an array you don't have to no nothing about its indexes, just use [`reset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php):

> reset() rewinds array's internal pointer to the first element and **returns the value of the first array element**.

```
$first = reset($images);
var_dump($first["sizes"]["thumbnail"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $images[0]['sizes']['thumbnail'];
```

Will get it

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $images[0]['sizes']['thumbnail']'
```